# Squarish HDRI shadows with irradiance volume in EEVEE

Tags: eevee-render-engine, hdri

As seen in the picture I get weird squarish shadows on the floor when baking the light of the HDRI with an irradiance volume. When I look at examples of others, the tones seem to nicely blend. Can someone tell me what I'm missing? Thank you.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened the project a few months later and it's gone. Probably just a bug which was fixed by an update.

Answer (score 0):

HDRI maps do not by themselves create shadows in Eevee-- only in Cycles. Also, your irradiance object is way too complex. It should probably be 1/10 or 1/20 of what you see there.

Not sure if this helps but those are some things you might take a look at.

Comment: I've tried both very low and a lot higher resolutions. It only changed the size of the rectangles.

Comment: You may need to up the size of your Shadows in the EEVEE Render Properties. Try setting them to 2048 (both Cube Size and Cascade Size) and see if that diesn't help. Also, look at upping the Cubemap Size in the Indirect Lighting EEVEE setting.